Why is there no work in a free and adiabatic expansion of a gas?
I recently came across the topic of irreversible expansion in thermodynamics. Suppose we have a container of gas with a piston (not mentioned whether massive or not), and we allow a free and adiabatic expansion until a certain volume. By the law of thermodynamics, work done and hence the change in internal energy, i.e. the temperature, is zero. However, when we consider the forces acting on the piston, they are clearly unbalanced and the work done on this does not come out to be zero, but rather equal to the integral of $p\mathrm{d}v$. Where does this difference in the work done (by the gas versus the atmosphere, here equal to zero) appear?

Does the piston gain kinetic energy?

work done is zero and the process being adiabatic makes the internal energy change zero, am I wrong in any manner, please correct me.

we are assuming the piston to be at rest during the final and initial stages so the kinetic energy gains are zero, do the other external forces contribute towards this?

Assume there is no piston, or that it can be ignored, otherwise it's not a free expansion. You are making the problem about the piston, when such questions are usually about the gases (the system).

If the piston is no longer moving in the final state, then the system has done no work

I believe there must be an external agent acting for a probably shorter period of time or else it won't be possible to stop the piston(theoretically)

If it helps, replace the piston with a wall between gas and vacuum, and have a tiny valve in that wall.

With a piston causing resistance against expansion, there is no free expansion.

While I do not understand the reason for the downvotes, let me start by correcting a misstatement in your question. You wrote "… hence the change in internal energy, i.e. the temperature, is zero." This is true only for the ideal gas, in fact the ideal gas is defined by the statement that its caloric equation of state is $U=f(T)$ and its thermal equation of state is $pV=g(T)$ for some continuous monotonic functions $f$ and $g$, but your question is more generally about an arbitrary gas not only the ideal gas. Now to your question.
You seem to assume a weightless piston pushed by the internal pressure of the gas moving in vacuum, or at least against zero outside pressure. While the $p\,\mathrm dV$ product and its integral $\int_{V_1}^{V_2}p\,\mathrm dV$ maybe meaningful at any instant, it does not represent work as it is normally understood unless the process is reversible in which case the external pressure equals the internal pressure of the gas, $p_\text{ext}=p$. Here by external pressure $p_\text{ext}$ is meant that of the environment that sustains only reversible processes. But in your example the environment is a vacuum and $p_\text{ext}=0$ and therefore the work done by the expanding gas on the environment is really zero not $\int p\,\mathrm dV$.
In your question, therefore, you are assuming an irreversible process that is also adiabatic. Assuming further that it is also quasistatic in the sense that its states are definable by equilibrium equations you still have Gibbs' equation valid $\mathrm dU=T\,\mathrm dS-p\,\mathrm dV+\mu\,\mathrm dN,$ with the constraints that $\mathrm dN=0$, representing a closed system to matter, and $\mathrm dS$ is the internally generated entropy for an adiabatic system; from these you get $\mathrm dU=T\,\mathrm dS-p\,\mathrm dV$ but nothing more. The latter equation integrated tells you that $\int_{V_1}^{V_2}p\,\mathrm dV=\int_{S_1}^{S_2}T\,\mathrm dS-(U_2-U_1).$
Since in an irreversible process $\mathrm dS\gt0$ the integral $\int_{S_1}^{S_2}T\,\mathrm dS\gt0$ and, consequently, $-\int_{V_1}^{V_2}p\,\mathrm dV\lt U_2-U_1=-\Delta U$ showing that the irreversible expansion lost useful workable energy that could have been extracted had the process been reversible adiabatic, i.e., one with $\mathrm dS=0$.
This lost work is compensated in the energy balance by the internal heat evolution in the amount of $T\,\mathrm dS$ and is represented by the continual increase of its internal entropy.

There are no forces acting on a piston during the free expansion of a gas. The Joule expansion experiment described at length  in the Wikipedia is a simpler way to describe a free expansion that does not involve hypothetical massless pistons. It assumes there is a sealed gap between two thermally insulated chambers, initially one containing a gas and one empty. The seal is breached, gas diffuses between the chambers, and the system is allowed to re-equilibrate. The gas does no work and no heat is exchanged. If the gas is ideal its internal energy and temperature remain constant.

For real gases, It can be useful to add it is an isenthalpic process.

@Poutnik I have thought about this but have trouble justifying. It is not a Joule-Thomson experiment because pressure is not controlled (no throttling), it is free expansion.

The W = Q = 0 remains. And the final state is the same. In my understanding, the throttling removes the problem how to manage the zero work while expanding.

@Poutnik So U2-U1=0 for free expansion, but this is not true for the JT experiment where U2-U1=p1V1-p2V2.

Hm, would have to think deeply about it, when having time and mood....  :-)

Work is the transfer of energy from one substance or system to another. In a free expansion into a vacuum the molecules of the gas encounter no other molecules to transfer energy to so the action is inherently adiabatic, it can lose no heat; it loses no energy, does no work, because the energy is the sum of the KE of the molecules and they are now flying unimpeded thruout the universe. [Please pardon the hyperbole.] The entropy of the gas has increased.
An actual substance has complications such as blackbody radiation from molecular collisions, the intermolecular attractions-repulsions resulting in the Joule-Thompson effect and just that they are not ideal gases. A free expansion is difficult to accomplish in the laboratory or on Earth or even on the Moon, possibly on the Space Station in zero gravity. It must involve expansion in 3 dimensions to allow conservation of momentum in the gas. It can be approximated by diffusion of two gases at the same T and P into each other, by the evaporation of a liquid in a vacuum; situations where the molecules are moving into the empty space between molecules.
